# headerRight is not working in ReactNative v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text,TouchableOpacity,Button} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import MaterialIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

import IndexScreen from './src/screens/IndexScreen'
import ShowScreen from './src/screens/ShowScreen'
import CreateScreen from './src/screens/CreateScreen'
import { Provider } from './src/context/BlogContext';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen 
          name="Index" 
          component={IndexScreen} 
          options={{ 
            headerTitle: "Blogs Screen", 
            headerRight: () => {
              // <Text>Hi There</Text>
              <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
              />
            }
          }}/>
        <AuthStack.Screen 
          name="Show" 
          component={ShowScreen} 
          options={{ title: "Show Screen" }}/>
        <AuthStack.Screen 
          name="Create" 
          component={CreateScreen} 
          options={{ 
            title: "Create Screen",
          }}
          />
      </AuthStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

// export default App;
export default () => {
  //This line for using ContextProvider to 
  //share data without using props
  return <Provider><App/></Provider>
}
```

I am trying to show a button which shows an alert on press, but nothing is showing up on the header bar. I am using reactNavigation v5. I am doing the same thing shown in the reactnavigation documentation page. Anyone have any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with react navigation when using header right on nested tab/stack navigation. So what I did was add header right from the component itself. So in your component, do this:

```
// Set header right button
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            headerRight: () => (
                <Button
                onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
                title="Info"
                color="#fff"
              />
            )
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: I did it and it worked. Doing this right from the component itself rather than doing it from the App.js file is better as we can also use the navigation props.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Pass screens options like this

```
<Stack.Screen 
name="Home" 
component={HomeScreen}
options={({ navigation }) => ({
title: 'Awesome app',
headerRight: () => (
  <DrawerButton onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()} />
),
})}
/>
```